# I'm in (name) and she's in math or she's in math class

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

Here in my country, the eleventh graders are spilt up into fields like Commerce ,Medical , Non-Medical , Humanities.
.
So here's some basic knowledge:

**Commerce: Business Studies, Economics, Math, Entrepreneurship.**
.
**Medical: Physics, Chemistry, Biology, Psychology.**

**Non-Medical: Physics, Chemistry, Math, IP**

**Humanities: History, Sociology, Psychology/Economics, Political Science.**

So someone comments:

> She's **in** Commerce.  (She took Commerce and she studies it)

Is the use of "in" natural?

And here's another context

---

A girl asks me about another girl, so can I say

> She's in Math.
>
> She's in the Math class.

She studies math and right now, she's in her math class.

So does "in" sound natural here?

Comment: It would be better to say _"She is taking the Commerce classes"_ . To say someone is "_in commerce_" usually means that they are working in a job that is classified as involving commerce. A similar phrase is "he is something in the city" which, in Britain, means that he works in the city of London and is understood to mean that the job is in banking or finance.
As for the second girl, in the UK you would say _"She's in the Maths class."_. Americans might use the other version.

Comment: So what do you think Americans might use @Peter Jennings ?

Comment: *She's in English* sound completely natural to me; I'm Canadian.  (I deliberately didn't use *Math* because of how it generally takes the plural form in the UK.)

Comment: So @JasonBassford, "she's in English" will be used to mean what? She's in the Wnglish class right now or she's take English classes?

Comment: And maybe you can answer the question to make it clearer... (difference b/w taking the class every day and attending the class right now...)